CQRobot Ocean: MCP23017 IO Expansion Board - "No pull up found"
I've got an IO Expansion board made by CQRobot that I'm trying to get working, but I can't get i2c to initialize.  Here's the board: http://www.cqrobot.wiki/index.php/MCP23017_IO_Expansion_Board_SKU:_CQRMCP23017A. I have SDA connected to Pin 1 (GPIO 0) and SDL connected to Pin 2 (GPIO 1).  For what it's worth, I have no trouble using an i2c LCD display on these pins.  The expansion boards have me stuck, though.
I'm using the following very simple code:
import busio
import board
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017

i2c = busio.I2C(board.GP1, board.GP0)
mcp = MCP23017(address=0x20, i2c=i2c)

This yields:
RuntimeError: No pull up found on SDA or SCL; check your wiring
I get the same error when trying an even simpler:
import board
i2c = board.STEMMA_I2C()

As I understand it, this board has its own pull-up resistors included, so I shouldn't be seeing any of this. The examples posted in the product wiki (linked above) and pics in the product reviews do not include any external pull-ups. I've tried adding my own 4.7K resistors from SDA and SCL to 5v VCC (VBUS), and then again with 10K resistors... There's no change in the error.
What am I missing?  Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

You haven't actually said what pins you connected. Adafruit uses its own names and it is unclear what they mean. Whatever you do DO NOT connect GPIO pins to 5V the Pico is a 3.3V device.

The board you linked has instructions for Pi, NOT Pico.

@Milliways: added pin connection info, and clarified that other i2c devices work fine on these pins.  Also, definitely agree with you - I'm not connecting GPIO pins directly to voltage.  I'm connecting the VCC pin of the IO expansion board to VBUS (pin 40) for 5v power.

What software are you using for these "other devices"? For that matter what software are you using for this task? Have you installed Adafruit Circuit Python?
